# How/what would I use in Node to scrape a <video> src?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm specifically trying to scrape the video src prop in this particular example link:

https://clips.twitch.tv/embed?clip=HyperHandsomeWatermelonTBTacoRight&tt_medium=clips_api&tt_content=embed

I've tried request-promise and cheerio, but unfortunately they don't allow scripts to load which I assume is necessary for this particular example.

I've tried puppeteer, which was successful in grabbing the video src link, but puppeteer would be extremely inefficient and slow for my purposes (scraping multiple links).

I've been trying JSDom due to the fact that it allows scripts to load prior to scraping, however i'm having trouble finding exactly how to use JSDom for my particular use case. Any help or insight would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I think this question is not related to reactjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the `<video>` element is not present in the response from the server. It appears only after some scripting has been done on the page, which runs in the browser.

To solve this problem, **you need a headless browser**, that can load pages, execute scripts, wait for network calls and code to render. You mention having trouble with performance when using Puppeteer, fortunately, there are many headless browsers, check out [this list of headless browsers](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers).

---

As for your specific case with Twitch.tv, how about just making a request to the Twitch API instead? [Check out the call to the status on your video.](https://clips.twitch.tv/api/v2/clips/HyperHandsomeWatermelonTBTacoRight/status)

Fetch the source from there instead:

```
function async getSrcFromUrl(url) {

    // Figure out how to parse the clip name (HyperHandsomeWatermelonTBTacoRight)
    const clip = getClipNameFromURL(url); 

    // Then fetch
    const status = JSON.parse(await request(`https://clips.twitch.tv/api/v2/clips/${clip}/status`));
    return status.quality_options[0].source;
}

const src = await getSrcFromUrl("https://clips.twitch.tv/embed?clip=HyperHandsomeWatermelonTBTacoRight&tt_medium=clips_api&tt_content=embed");
```

Comment: You may have just saved my life. I was at Twitch talking to the head developer of their API asking about this particular question and never got this answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: Happy to help :)